# AD Searchfilter are not working in Java Code but working using ldp client

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=dc=pc,dc=com))
```

This search filter gives a result when used with ldp client.

but in java code this returns Result set empty.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try :

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=(dc=pc,dc=com)))
```

or

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member='dc=pc,dc=com'))
```

An according to [Microsoft recomandations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it would be better to write :

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(dc=pc,dc=com)))
```